# Grep output on seperate line

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have the below script:

```
#!/bin/bash
   while read -r i; do
  autorep -j $i -q | grep -e insert_job -e date_conditions -e condition | awk '{print ($2,$4,$6)}'
echo
 done
```

i get the output

```
Test_Kill CMD
0
Test_Karthik CMD
0
Test_Ujjal CMD
0
Test1 CMD
0
```

when i modify the script to:

```
   #!/bin/bash
  while read -r i; do
     autorep -j $i -q | grep -e insert_job -e date_conditions -e condition | awk 'BEGIN { ORS=" " }; {print ($2,$4,$6)}'
     echo
  done
```

I get the output as:

```
Test_Kill CMD  0   Test_Karthik CMD  0   Test_Ujjal CMD  0   Test1 CMD  0
```

What i am looking for is if i can get the output like below:

```
Test_Kill CMD  0
Test_Karthik CMD  0
Test_Ujjal CMD  0
Test1 CMD  0
```

EDIT:

below is the autorep output

```
 autorep -j test_ujjal -q


/* ----------------- test_ujjal ----------------- */

insert_job: test_ujjal   job_type: CMD
command: echo
machine: vservername
owner: owner
permission:
date_conditions: 0
description: "test job"
alarm_if_fail: 0
alarm_if_terminated: 0
```

Comment: please update the question to show the complete output from a couple `autorep -j $i -q` calls; since you're already using `awk` there's likely a much simpler solution

Comment: This is just a slight permutation of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74743362/while-loop-output-on-separate-line - don't do that. Go back and edit your existing posts rather than post another, or at least delete the old one.

Comment: Your last script will format exactly as you wanted if you get rid of the awk  ORS reset (delete the entire block `BEGIN { ORS=" " };`) I don't know why you would have included that but that is the reason your output is on one line, you have overridden the default new line output separator.

Comment: `job_type: CMD` in not on a line by itself? Is `condition:` the whole key when it shows? Because as-is, `condition` will also be matched on `date_conditions`, but (I assume) harmlessly...

Comment: Job_type is not on a different line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `autorep` output is:

```
/* ----------------- test_ujjal ----------------- */

insert_job: test_ujjal   job_type: CMD
command: echo
machine: vservername
owner: owner
permission:
date_conditions: 0
description: "test job"
alarm_if_fail: 0
alarm_if_terminated: 0
```

The following `awk` might work for you:

```
awk '/insert_job/ {printf "%s %s ", $2, $4}; /date_conditions|condition/ {printf "%s\n", $2}' < <(autorep .....)
```

Example with `autorep` output stored in file `ar.out`:

```
awk '/insert_job/ {printf "%s %s ", $2, $4}; /date_conditions|condition/ {printf "%s\n", $2}' ar.out 
test_ujjal CMD 0
```

Comment: the above command has solved the problem, now the data is coming as i wanted but i have one more issue at hand.

The data that i am getting is as below:

Test_Kill CMD 0
Test_Karthik CMD 0
Test_Ujjal CMD 0
Test1 CMD 0

and i want to send this data to a .csv file but all the data is coming in just 1 column. 

command that i am using is:

(echo "job name,job type,Date Conditions,conditions" ; cat test1.txt) | sed 's/;/<tab>/g' > Test1.csv

but when i open the .csv file everything is coming under the "Job Name" column